# Java - (LinkedList.get(var) == null) doesn't work

Tags: java, for-loop, linked-list, null

I'm getting an error when Im trying to get the index from a LinkedList, I insert 1 value at the 0 position, so when I ask if the next position is null then print something.

```
            int i;
            int sum;
            for(i=0; i<list.size();i++){
                if(i == 0){
                    sum = i + 1;
                    if(list.get(sum) == null){

                        System.out.println("["+list.get(i) +"," + "Null" + "]" + " <-- Cabecera");
                    }
                    else{
                     System.out.println("["+list.get(i) +"," + sum + "]" + " <-- Cabecera");
                   }

                }

               else {
                sum = i + 1;
                    if(list.get(sum) == null){
                        System.out.println("["+list.get(i) +"," + "Null" + "]");
                    }
                    else{
                        System.out.println("["+list.get(i) +"," + sum + "]");
                    }

                }
```

but I keep having this
ERROR: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1

Answer (score 3):

The problem is this part:

```
sum = i + 1;
if(list.get(sum) == null){
```

`i` is guaranteed to be a valid index by the loop condition in the `for` statement,
but `i + 1` is not.
When `i` is equal to `list.size() - 1` (index of the last element),
you will get an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`,
as that is accessing beyond the end of the list.

Btw, keep in mind that the `get` method is not efficient for linked lists.
You should either refactor your code to use a for-each loop, or change the list implementation to something with efficient random access, such as `ArrayList`.

Comment: So, when im trying to get any position outOfBounds , that doesn't act like a null value? something that doesn't exist?

Comment: @BrianCas that's right: accessing out of bounds doesn't return null, it throws an exception. This is the behavior of arrays and lists. Maybe you confuse with a map. If you try to get a key from a map that doesn't exist, you will get a null. You can read about this in the javadoc.

Comment: @BrianCas No. You should read the javadoc of the [`get(int index)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get-int-) method: *Throws `IndexOutOfBoundsException` - if the index is out of range `(index < 0 || index >= size())`*

Comment: Thank you very much, I'm just starting with Java, I'll keep in mind to read the documentation, btw, I found a solution using **if(list.indexOf(sum) == -1**